# ¿Cómo obtengo el SHA para subir mi aplicación a play store para que se vean los mapas?

Tags: android-studio, api, app-store

Subí mi aplicación a la **Play Store**. Al momento de descargarla los mapas no se visualizan, la clave **api** tiene la huella digital de lanzamiento que la obtengo desde:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

Pero los mapas no se ven.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes obtener el SHA-1 de tu keystore con el cual firmaras tu aplicación para la PlayStore:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posteriormente con ese SHA-1, lo registras para el paquete de tu aplicación y obtienes la API Key, esta API Key será la que utilices para la aplicación que e publique en Google Play Store.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]